# $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] doesn't work when I use auto_prepend_file

Tags: php, apache2

For some reasons, I have to use `auto_prepend_file` (http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) to load a `var.php` file with some variables. But I can see that some variables like `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` doesn't work except when I'm on the file that's called.

If I go to the `index.php`, the variable is empty. Is it possible to get around this?

Comment: can you write a fuller example of what you are referring to? its difficult to understand the question currently

Comment: I can't reproduce this. We use `auto-prepend-file` and `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` still works for us.

Comment: We're doing this in PHP 7.0, our auto-prepend file is used to load some shims for backward compatibility.

Comment: Might both depend on [auto_globals_jit](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-globals-jit) and variables_order.

Answer (score -1):

Seems that designed behavior. Try to store this vars somewhere in prepend file and then load.

I have check php.manual, no words about this, but try.

What it will output:

```
<?php
phpinfo(32);
?>
```

Also:

> Be warned that most contents of the Server-Array (even
>   $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) are provided by the client and can be
>   manipulated. They can also be used for injections and thus MUST be
>   checked and treated like any other user input.

Comment: I don't think so. We use `auto-prepend-file` and `HTTP_USER_AGENT` works fine for us.

Comment: This can be different between versions

Comment: Possibly. We're using 7.0.